# error : Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object to JSONObject

Tags: android

Getting the above error in the following code

```
MainActivity.get("statuses/public_timeline.json", null,
            new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {
                public void onSuccess(JSONArray timeline) {
                    // Pull out the first event on the public timeline
                    JSONObject firstEvent = timeline.get(0);
                    String tweetText = firstEvent.getString("text");

                    // Do something with the response
                    System.out.println(tweetText);
                }
            });
```

in the above code here timeline.get(0) getting the error.could any one suggest suitable solution for this
thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try to add cast to `(JSONObject)timeline.get(0)`?. Before, add validation like `if(timeline.size > 0)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

replace this line

```
 JSONObject firstEvent = timeline.get(0);
```

with

```
 JSONObject firstEvent = timeline.getJSONObject(0);
```

and it will work like a charm. or you can also cast it to `JSONObject` like Maxim suggested.

```
 JSONObject firstEvent = (JSONObject)timeline.get(0);
```

also add basic checks for null or if JsonArray actually holds any object, and add try catch too.

Answer (score 1):

What does `timeline.get(0)` return? Does return JSONObject or String? If returns String than you should do `JSONObject firstEvent = new JSONObject(timeline.get(0));`

Comment: So I made a fool of myself :)) of course timeline.get(0) return a JSONArray, I should be more careful when reading code